# Como passar um array de objetos StdClass php para uma variável JS usando $.ajax() jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho a estrutura abaixo. Preciso acessar cada valor no jquery.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 140
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 141
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 142
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converta o objeto em JSON ao responder ao jQuery:

```
<?php

$o1 = new stdClass;
$o1->post_id = 140;

$o2 = new stdClass;
$o2->post_id = 141;

$arr = array($o1, $o2);

echo json_encode($arr);
// [{"post_id":140},{"post_id":141}]
```

Comment: para auxiliar o colega: http://ideone.com/sMTVM2

Answer (score 2):

Pegue esse array, mande como um json para o javascript

```
<?php
   $arr = array(array('id' => 1 ), array('id' => 2 ), array('id' => 3 ));
   echo json_encode($arr);
```

No javascript transforme essa string em um json e depois pode acessar ele conforme o código abaixo. No do `1` troque isso por uma variável em `for`.

```
.done(function(msg) {
      var response = JSON.parse(msg);
      alert(response[1].id);
//demais códigos ...
```